# Should we apply as many tags as we can?

Tags: discussion, tags

Consider this scenario: A new user asked a question and tagged it [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), but from the supplied code we can't predict the type of application (ASP, Winforms, WPF); after getting the information from the user I have re-tagged it to [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net). But it is possible to tag them with a few more categories.

Here my question is that, is it a good practice here to tag a particular questions with all possible tags? I hope it will help the questions to get more audience.

Comment: The more focused the tags are the more useful.

Answer (score 11):

Tags should reflect what's *important* about the question's *problem domain*. They should not reflect everything that could, conceivably, be relevant at some point. That's what the question itself is for.

So tagging with a bunch of possibilities is just noisy, since chances are none of them is actually important to the question.

SO has a bit of a special case with language tags, since those are relevant and narrow down the problem domain often enough that they usually get included even if, strictly speaking, they aren't crucial. (They're also very handy for following.) But other than those, don't use a tag just because it *could* be applied to the question; tag it because it *must* be applied.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Nathan's answer, I want to emphasize that there's a limit of five tags per question, but it's not necessary to always use five.

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880028/to-assign-values-to-a-dictionary) for example, you added the [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) tag. That tag is not relevant to the question, which is about assigning a  value to a read-only property. It doesn't matter what the types of this value and the property are. That the type of the problematic property happens to be `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` doesn't mean the [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) tag is relevant to the question.

As for the [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net), [winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms), [console-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console-application), [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) tags and so on: they are about *application frameworks*. When the question merely deals with basic language constructs and framework features (assigning variables, polymorphism, standard library types and functions such as sets, dictionaries, math, Linq), then the application framework tags are irrelevant. They do not help narrow down the scope of the question. Math does not change between ASP.NET and WinForms.

You apply the [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) tag when the question is about the HTTP pipeline, or sessions, or application lifecycle events.

You apply the [winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) tag when the question is specifically about a WinForms constructs, such as handling Windows messages, laying out controls, or handling specific input events.

You apply the [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) tag when a question is about XAML markup or the use of commands or converters.

And so on, and so on. Don't just apply a tag because a word occurs within a question that happens to be a tag also.

Comment: *"Math does not change between ASP.NET and WinForms."* Except when it does, then you've *really* got a question! :-)

Comment: @CodyGray .NET WinForms arithmetic considered harmful. Film at 11.